# Type ahead search doesn't work when tried from Task module

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

When I try to write something in the `Input.choices` component, it doesn't invoke `onInvokeActivity` while using it from the Task module, I see there's this issue already mentioned around several months ago, but MSFT teams couldn't share the ETA, please help if you come across this and have solved it.
I am attaching the sample code and the `onInvokeActivity` method here.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Heading",
          "wrap": true,
          "size": "Small",
          "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
          "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
          "placeholder": "Select something",
          "isRequired": true,
          "errorMessage": "Select at least one",
          "id": "userId",
          "choices": "${choices}",
          "choices.data": {
            "type": "Data.Query",
            "dataset": "hello"
          },
          "spacing": "None",
          "style": "filtered",
          "value": "${defaultChoice}"
        }
      ],
      "spacing": "ExtraLarge"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "data": {
        "commandId": "commandId",
        "msteams": {
          "type": "invoke",
          "value": {
            "type": "task/submit"
          }
        }
      },
      "title": "Submit",
      "type": "Action.Submit"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.3"
}
```

```
protected async onInvokeActivity(
    context: TurnContext
  ): Promise<InvokeResponse<any>> {
    if (context.activity.name === "application/search") {
       const { queryText, dataset } = context.activity.value;
       if (dataset === "hello") {
          console.log({ queryText });
       }
    }
}
```

Network tab response while typing:

```
{
    "statusCode": 504,
    "message": "App is not installed"
}
```

Comment: @Yogendra-Are you facing same issue like in this thread-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/422

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - yes same issue in Task module

Comment: @Yogendra- We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - thanks, hope it gets resolved soon :)

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT have you got any ETA on the same?

Comment: @Yogendra-Issue is fixed with the latest version. Could you please check it once with the updated version. Now we are able to see the List.
Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.24124 (64-bit)-E.